# Class members and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, member

I am lost. I have a class `Editor` and a class `Controller`. Classes `WorkflowEditor` and `WorkflowController` derive from `Editor` and `Controller` respectively. Class `Controller` has a protected member `Editor editor` and class `WorkflowController` has a private member `WorkflowEditor editor` (with same name).

---

**Edit from EitanT**:
Here's a simplified code snipped to illustrate what the OP has described:

```
class Controller
{
    Editor editor;
    // ...
}

class WorkflowEditor : public Editor {
    // ...
};

class WorkflowController : public Controller {
    WorkflowEditor editor;
    // ...
};
```

---

My application is a module with graphical interface. In workflow mode, a ribbon appears on Launch, and a wizard is displayed. On click on one button, a method in class `Controller` is called. Execution crashes because at this time, `Editor editor` class member of object with type `Controller` is dead. I would like class member `Editor editor` to be the same as class member `WorkflowEditor editor` (same name).

In other words, if a class `A` has a member of class `B` and class `childA` (derived from `A`) has a member of class `childB` (derived from `B`), and member of type `childB` and `B` have same name, isn't the member "inherited"?

Comment: It is hard to see what your problem is without the actual code. Reduce the problem to a minimal code sample and post it (it is hard from a textual description to understand if you are holding the member by pointer/reference/value, or how many instances of each object there are lying around)

Comment: @dlib _...isn't the member inherited?_: in short, no.

Comment: @EitanT: A longer but more correct answer would be "yes".

Comment: @MikeSeymour :) My longer answer would be, that it _is_ inherited, except not as the same `member`, but rather `childA::member`. **EDIT:** I see that you've already stated that in your answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is inherited, but is *not* the same object as the one declared in the derived class. The derived class member is a separate object to the base class member, even though they have the same name. Technically, it *hides* the base class member, making it accessible only with its qualified name, `Controller::editor`.

You can achieve what you want with a virtual function, which you override in the derived class to access an object contained there:

```
class Controller {
public:
    // No data members, just an abstract interface

    // Access a data member of the derived class
    virtual Editor & editor() = 0;
    virtual ~Controller() {}
};

class WorkflowController : public Controller {
public:
    WorkflowEditor & editor() {return editor_;}

private:
    // The object itself - accessible as its true type here, or
    // as its abstract type via the abstract interface.
    WorkflowEditor editor_;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The member in the derived class hides the member in the base class.

Comment: And you can access the hidden base class member by qualifying the name: `Base::member`